# Encountered Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression 00979. 00000 - "not a GROUP BY expression"

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I want to join 3 table together and display the output as below.But i encountered the error when i tried to use group by and order by together. Is there any solution can solve this error? Below is my Oracle query. Appreciate if someone could help on this error. Thank you.

1. The database data is like below:
   This is my **1st table** (RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo):

> ```
>        ID                           KEY               VALUE
> AD9FBCCC49F06446E050280A2         Quantity            100
> AD9FBCCC49F06446E050280A2        PackageLeads         BN1140
> AD9FBCCC49F06446E050280A2        TestProgram          DL_FP5_SLT
> AD9FBCCC49F06446E050280A2          TestRev            3.0.0
> AD9FBCCC49F06446E050280A2           IDV               9651AA43
> ```

**Second Table** as below (RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity):

```
EQP_ID  LOT_ID   ACTIVITY  MODIFIED BY  MODIFIED DATE              ID
LAS43   9KA2909  LOAD_LOT  jratnasa     18-AUG-20       AD9FBCCC49F06446E050280A2
```

**Third Table** (RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_rescreen)

```
       ID                        RESCREEN TYPE
AD9FBCCC49F06446E050280A2           FRESH
```

2. The output i want is group all same ID as below and display in gridview but i am not sure is it possible to do that?

**The final output should be like this:**

```
EQP_ID   MODIFIED DATE         ID                            name
LAS43    18-AUG-20       AD9FBCCC49F06446E050280A2        Quantity:100,
                                                          PackageLeads:BN1140,
                                                          TestProgram:DL_FP5_SLT,  
                                                          TestRev:3.0.0,                                
                                                          IDV:9651AA43
```

3. i come up with this query, but seem like it does not working.

```
SELECT RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.EQP_ID,
       RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE,
       RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.ID,
       LISTAGG(RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.KEY) 
              WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.KEY) as "names"
from RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity 
INNER JOIN RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_rescreen 
    ON RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.ID = RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_rescreen.ID 
INNER JOIN RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo 
    ON RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.ID = RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.ID 
WHERE RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE BETWEEN'01-Jan-2020'AND '30-Sep-2020'
GROUP BY RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.ID,
         RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.KEY,
         RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.EQP_ID
order by RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE ASC
```

Comment: `RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE` is not listed in GROUP BY expresion. Either add or wrap it in output list with some aggregate function (MAX for example). And I think that you must remove `RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.KEY` from GROUP BY expression - it is strange to apply LISTAGG to single value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below. Check your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` statements always with the `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY`

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) some other usages of `LISTAGG` in case you need them.

```
  SELECT RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.EQP_ID,
         RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE,
         RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.ID,
         LISTAGG (RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.KEY)
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.KEY)
            AS "names"
    FROM RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity
         INNER JOIN RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_rescreen
            ON RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.ID = RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_rescreen.ID
         INNER JOIN RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo
            ON RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.ID = RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.ID
   WHERE RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE BETWEEN '01-Jan-2020'
                                                   AND '30-Sep-2020'
GROUP BY RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity_lotinfo.ID,
         RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE,
         RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.EQP_ID
ORDER BY RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE ASC
```

As your intended output try below. I did not know what which id you need and where is the VALUE column comes from. I know you can manage though.

```
 SELECT RMSTMP_PNG.OTA_ACTIVITY.EQP_ID AS ID,
         LISTAGG (RMSTMP_PNG.OTA_ACTIVITY_LOTINFO.KEY || ':' || VALUE, ',')
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RMSTMP_PNG.OTA_ACTIVITY.MODIFIED_DATE)
            AS "names"
    FROM RMSTMP_PNG.OTA_ACTIVITY
         INNER JOIN RMSTMP_PNG.OTA_ACTIVITY_RESCREEN
            ON RMSTMP_PNG.OTA_ACTIVITY.ID = RMSTMP_PNG.OTA_ACTIVITY_RESCREEN.ID
         INNER JOIN RMSTMP_PNG.OTA_ACTIVITY_LOTINFO
            ON RMSTMP_PNG.OTA_ACTIVITY.ID = RMSTMP_PNG.OTA_ACTIVITY_LOTINFO.ID
   WHERE RMSTMP_PNG.OTA_ACTIVITY.MODIFIED_DATE BETWEEN '01-Jan-2020'
                                                   AND '30-Sep-2020'
GROUP BY RMSTMP_PNG.OTA_ACTIVITY_LOTINFO.ID
ORDER BY RMSTMP_PNG.OTA_ACTIVITY.MODIFIED_DATE
```

Comment: Hi ismetguzelgun, i tried to run the code, seem like it return me the same error. Thanks

Comment: Edited my answer. Try it @Yong

Comment: Hi @ismetguzelgun, if without 'RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.EQP_ID' then it is work, but in this query i need to have 'RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.EQP_ID' because the data will display in gridview and at the same time i need to have order by 'RMSTMP_PNG.ota_activity.MODIFIED_DATE' to make sure the date is ACS. Thanks

Comment: @Yong Edited. Try pls

Comment: This should work with any given group by statement unless it is also in the select. If my last edit still does not work please share some sample data and we can see what will happen then. @Yong

Comment: @Yong Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Hi ismetguzelgun, i already tried but it return me same error. sorry for late reply, today quite busy .

Comment: Hi @ismetguzelgun, i already share some sample of data :)

Comment: Hi @ismetguzelgun, are you edit the query? because i tried to use the first query that you gave, its working now.

Comment: @Yong There should be no problem with queries. If it did produce result you want accept it already :)

Comment: Hi @ismethuzelgun, thank you so much . You save me again 